# Save (encrypted) password with Powermail (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, password-encryption, powermail

I use powermail to create fe_users for TYPO3, which works fine so far.

Only the password is written in plain text in the DB, do any of you have an idea how to manage that the password is stored encrypted after saving?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fe_users records with powermail (I would use a registration extension for this task), then you could use finisher methods (see https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses.md) and convert the password before saving.
If you are using the existing saveToAnyTable finisher, you could use a TypoScript UserFunc for the field password. That could convert the value.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. in the normal case femanager or similar would be sufficient in this case i solved it via powermail because the login data is still written in other tables than fe_users. I will try to implement this with the user function.